# HTML5 Video - run events if currentTime equals set time

Tags: javascript, html, html5-video, dom-events

I am trying to catch certain events while a *html5* `video` is playing. I want to trigger them at the 5, 10, 15, 20 and 25 second marks during playback.

Below is the code that I have running:

```
this.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
  if (e.target.currentTime >= 5) {
    console.log('5 seconds')
  } else if (e.target.currentTime >= 10) {
    console.log('10 seconds')
  }
})
```

This seems to work only on the first `if` statement `(currentTime >= 5)`. It never runs the `else if` though. When I try and be exact and change `>=` to a set equal to `==` it doesn't even run at all.

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated. I'm also open to other suggestions of a better way to do this.

I'm reading this article and not sure if it's suitable or not: [Syncing content with html5 video](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2011/03/syncing-content-with-html5-video/)

Comment: try console.log(e.target.currentTime). It will not return exactly 4.0 or 5.0 seconds. So you can modify the if condition and check something between >= 5 && <= 6 seconds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After video crossed the 5th sec , the first statement will always be true because all seconds after 5th are `>=5` so it never fall into `else`. You have 2 approach ahead

1) Use range:

```
this.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
    if (5 <= e.target.currentTime && e.target.currentTime < 10) {
        console.log('5 seconds')
    } else if (10 <= e.target.currentTime && e.target.currentTime < 25) {
        console.log('10 seconds')
    }
});
```

2) Do reverse (in placement) `if/else`

```
this.video.addEventListener('timeupdate', (e) => {
    if (e.target.currentTime > 25) {
        console.log('25+ seconds')
    } else if (e.target.currentTime > 20) {
        console.log('25-20 seconds')
    } else if (e.target.currentTime > 15) {
        console.log('20-15 seconds')
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks @nikc.org. This has seemed to work perfectly.

Comment: You're very kind. It is however @Colin Cline who should get all the honors, not me.

Comment: @nikc.org No worries man, thanks to you for edit. But i lost 20 rep after your edit approved, this is bug or this is just part of SO rules (did something happens to upvotes after edits?)? P.S i checked all activities tab and no one down voted me but in my browser in one tab i had this page before your edit and in another this page with your edit (some how first one was time outed and didnt refreshed) but there were 20 rep difference in 2 tab.

Comment: In all honesty I don't know, but that would be a strange feature I would think.

Comment: @ColinCline from what I can tell, my editing should not have cost you any lost reputation, have a look at the 'You lose reputation when' section here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation